# Why does this grep command not work?

Tags: services, grep

When I try to use grep in this fashion:

```
service --status-all | grep network
```

It still lists all the services even though I piped it into `grep` to restrict it to the "network" string only

---

> **After the Fact:**
>
> Noticed this [article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70112/why-does-service-status-all-output-to-stderr-instead-of-stdin) that explains why the command behaves this way, that's what I like about linux, there is always a good reason, but not necessary intuitive

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try:

```
service --status-all |& grep network
```

Command-line applications can print to two text streams known as *standard out* (stdout) and *standard error* (stderr). By default, the terminal just displays the output for both identically.

Stdout is given the number 1, and stderr is given the number 2. By default, redirection operators, like `>`, `|` and `<` apply only to stdout, number 1.

`|&` pipes both stdout and stderr together to the process on the right's standard input (stdin) stream, which makes `grep` work as you expected.

I don't know why `service --status-all` is printing to stderr here, but in general, having a separate stderr stream is very useful, as it lets you see errors even when stdout is silenced.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, seems this has generated a lot of interest. So I guess I wasn't the only one with this issue.

Answer (score 4):

You need to redirect [standard error stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error_stream#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) (`2`) to [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error_stream#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) (`1`):

```
service --status-all 2>&1 | grep network
```

Operator `>` normally redirects to file (e.g. `2>/tmp/file`). To redirect to other stream using [descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), it needs to be preceded with `&` (note no spaces between characters).